# Flex : How to apply style name to the component fx:Component

Tags: css, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have style name called LabelArabicFontTrue and apply it to all labels and buttons worked successful my issue is it doesn't apply the style with labels in fx:Component 
my code :

```
        <fx:Component className="Internet">
        <s:SkinnablePopUpContainer >
            <s:TitleWindow title="تنبيه" close="close()">
                <s:VGroup horizontalAlign="center" paddingTop="8" paddingBottom="8" paddingLeft="8" paddingRight="8" gap="5" width="100%">
                    <s:Label styleName="LabelArabicFontTrue" text="لا يوجد انترنت" />
                    <s:Button label="اغلاق" click="close();" skinClass="Skins.ArabicLang" styleName="buttonArabicFontTrue"/>
                </s:VGroup>
            </s:TitleWindow>
        </s:SkinnablePopUpContainer>
    </fx:Component>
```

and call it in script

```
(new Internet()).open(this, false) ;
```

then how to apply the style to the label

Note : button in component work success the problem occur in label only

please help

Comment: There is no component named `component` and as such you can't apply styles to it.  You should apply the styles to the SkinnablePopUpContainer.  What is the context you're using this code in?

Comment: i use it to make a popup message

Comment: Could you post your style markup?